# Tortoisesvn problem with external only on my pc

Tags: tortoisesvn

Details:

Tortoisesvn client (latest version)
Windows Vista.

Yesterday I wanted to add an external directory. I made a mistake with the external path (I wrote an error in the url) and now I am constantly getting these error messages:

```
External failed , could not resolve hostname.
```

This is correct because I made a mistake in my external. Now when i go to 
SVN > properties. I am not able to change the property because the property window is empty.

Others don't have this problem. I tried to remove the repository and restart my pc and check it out again. But this didn't help.

Any Idea's? Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On updating *which* folder does SVN give this error message? Have you looked at *that* folder's properties?

Comment: any folder. the root folder a sub folder doesn't make a difference what folder.

Comment: My point was: Are you sure that you're looking at the properties of the right folder? (You might want to look at the project's history to find out where the external was added to.)